# MVVM WPF Interface freezes when setting the ItemsSource collection in async method

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm, async-await

I have a problem with a ListView. When the `ObservableCollection` that is the ItemsSource is set, the application freezes for a few seconds.

This is the list view:

```
 <UserControl.Resources>

            <CollectionViewSource x:Key="Sets" Source="{Binding Path=Entries}">
                <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                    <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="DailySet.WeeklySet" />
                    <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="DailySet" />
                </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            </CollectionViewSource>
        <utilities:InvertableBooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding IsAsync=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DataContext="{StaticResource Sets}"   >
        <ListView.View >
                <GridView >
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding StartTimeFormatted}" Header="Start" Width="60"  />
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding EndTimeFormatted}" Header="End" Width="60"  />
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding TotalHoursFormatted}" Header="Time" Width="80"  />
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CostCode}" Header="CostCode" Width="120"  />
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Operation}" Header="Operation" Width="160" />
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Comment}" Header="Comment"  >
                    <GridViewColumn.Width>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource LastColumnMaximizerConverter}">
                            <Binding Path="ActualWidth" 
                                         RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}"/>
                            <Binding Path="View.Columns" 
                                         RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </GridViewColumn.Width>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Action" Width="60">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate >
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                                <Button IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=thisUc, Path=DataContext.EditingAllowed}"
                                        BorderThickness="0" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent" ToolTip="Edit this entry"
                                        Command="{Binding ElementName=thisUc, Path=DataContext.EditEntryCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                                    <Button.Content>
                                        <Image Height="18" Width="20" Source="pack://application:,,,/Gfx/edit.png"></Image>
                                    </Button.Content>
                                </Button>

                                <Button IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=thisUc, Path=DataContext.EditingAllowed}" BorderThickness="0" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent" ToolTip="Delete this entry"
                                    Command="{Binding ElementName=thisUc, Path=DataContext.DeleteEntryCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                                <Button.Content>
                                    <Image Height="18" Width="20" Source="pack://application:,,,/Gfx/delete.png"></Image>
                                </Button.Content>
                            </Button>
 </StackPanel>

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        <ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,5"/>
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                    <Expander IsExpanded="{Binding Path=Name.IsWeekOpen, Mode=OneWay}" >
                                        <Expander.Header>
                                           ... header label definition
                                        </Expander.Header>
                                        <Expander.Content>
                                            <ItemsPresenter />
                                        </Expander.Content>
                                    </Expander>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            </GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,0,10,5"/>
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                    <Expander IsExpanded="False" BorderBrush="#FFA4B97F" 
                                              BorderThickness="0,0,0,1"  IsEnabled="{Binding Path=Name.DayDetailsGroupingHeader.RealEntriesAvailable}">
                                        <Expander.Header>
                                         ... header label definition
                                        </Expander.Header>
                                        <Expander.Content>
                                            <ItemsPresenter />
                                        </Expander.Content>
                                    </Expander>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListView.GroupStyle>
</ListView>
```

This is the method that populates the entries list:

```
public override async Task LoadLiveData()
{            
    IEnumerable<DailyDetailedInfo> details = await this.Connector.GetDetails();

    List<DailyDetailEntry> entries = this.Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<DailyDetailedInfo>, IEnumerable<DailyDetailEntry>>(details).ToList();
    //up to this point the execution takes ~300-500 miliseconds

    this.Entries = new ObservableCollection<DailyDetailEntry>(entries.OrderBy(x => x.ExtractedStartDate));
    // collection assigning takes few miliseconds as well
    //this.Entries = new ObservableCollection<DailyDetailEntry>(); when empty collection is assigned, the UI is not frozen, even though the Connector.GetDetails() is called
}
```

I am sure that there are no CPU bound operations, and the problem only happens when the `this.Entries` collection is assigned. 
I tried replacing the `this.Entries` assignment with an empty collection and it works fine in such case.

I also tried adding items one by one, but no change:

```
foreach (DailyDetailEntry dailyDetailEntry in entries.OrderBy(x => x.ExtractedStartDate))
{
    this.Entries.Add(dailyDetailEntry);
}
```

What should I do to make the UI responsive?

Comment: As a note, setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the ItemsSource Binding is pointless. It has no effect. I also doubt that `IsAsync=True` has any effect, because it just calls the source property getter asynchronously, which only returns the collection instance. It is also unclear how Entries is related to the ItemsSource Binding at all, as there is no Binding Path.

Comment: Approximately how many items are in the list, and how complex is the template that the list is bound to?  You may need to look in to virtualizing the the control that the list is bound to, so that only visible templates are created, and recycled.

Comment: @BradleyUffner - between 50 and 100 - however, the template might be a bit complex due to 2 level grouping of items

Comment: A `ListView` what shows multiple `GridView` controls seems like it would be VERY expensive.  Especially one showing 50-100 GridViews.  Each of those GridViews is being instantiated on the UI thread when the `ObservableCollection` is assigned.

Comment: You might be able to speed it up by virtualizing the `ListView`, but that might not even be enough.  Are you defining the columns on the `GridView` explicitly, or are you letting it infer them?  If the grids have a lot of rows themselves, they will probably need to be virtualized also.  Explicit columns would also be faster.  I'm not convinced there will be any way to make a `ListView` of `GridView` controls really fast though.

Comment: @BradleyUffner - thanks - I have updated the XAML in the question with the entire listview definition.

Comment: Ahh, that's helpful.  You aren't actually creating multiple `GridView` controls like I thought.

Comment: `ListView` virtualizes items by default, but grouping disables the virtualization.  That's probably the performance killer, as it looks like your template is fairly expensive.  Is there any other way you could lay out your content to get the same effect as grouping, without actually using grouping (nested `ItemsControl`s for example)?

Comment: @BradleyUffner - potentially I can. That's quite a change though. So, as far as I understand, its basically a limitation of the ListView?

Comment: Yeah, it's an odd ListView quirk. It stops virtualizing if you even look at it funny. You can verify by using the live layout tree thing in VS to inspect the ListView to see if `IsVirtualizing` is still set.